# "Database does not exist" sfDatabaseException in symfony 1.4x

Tags: php, mysql, symfony-1.4, propel

error :

```
Database "mtlindia" does not exist.

http://localhost/training/web/index.php
```

- i  have refered this link http://www.lampjunkie.com/2008/05/store-symfony-sessions-in-database-with-propel/ after spending hours cannot solve this issue.

changes in files that i made

1. training/apps/frontend/config/factories.yml

   ```
   storage:
    class: sfPDOSessionStorage        # sfNoStorage disables session storage completely.
   param:
   db_table: sessions      # Name of the table storing the sessions
   database: mtlindia          # Name of the database connection to use
   # Optional parameters
   db_id_col: session_id           # Name of the column storing the session id
   db_data_col: value              # Name of the column storing the session data
   db_time_col: created_datetime   # Name of the column storing the session timestamp
   ```
2. database.yml

   ```
      prod:
     propel:
    param:
    hostspec:           mydataserver
   username:           myusername
   password:           xxxxxxxxxx

   all:
   propel:
    class:                sfPropelDatabase
    param:
   phptype:            mysql     # Database vendor
    hostspec:           localhost
   database:           mtlindia
    username:           root
   password:           
    port:               80
    encoding:           utf8      # Default charset for table creation
    persistent:         true      # Use persistent connections
   ```
3. database.yml.dst

   ```
       dev:
     propel:
       param:
         classname:  DebugPDO
         host:       'ucudev_mtl'
         dsn:        'oci:dbname=mtlindia'
         username:   root
         password:   
     sessions_db:
       class:        sfPDODatabase
       param:
         classname:  DoctrinePDO
         dsn:        'oci:dbname=mtlindia'
         username:   root
         password:  
         encoding:   utf8
         persistent: false
         pooling:    false
   ```

   - i  have tried to flush cache in windows .
   - any suggestion is most welcome though im new in symfony 1.4 version.

error

```
500 | Internal Server Error | sfDatabaseException
 Database "mtlindia" does not exist.

 stack trace
at ()
in SF_ROOT_DIR\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\database\sfDatabaseManager.class.php line 109 ...
  }


   // nonexistent database name

   throw new sfDatabaseException(sprintf('Database "%s" does not exist.', $name));

  }
```

- i have google & find out problem is in database.yml file can anyone help where i have done wrong in database.yml file.
- i have also reffer http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/pdo_session_storage.html

Comment: are you able to connect to `sessions_db` manually?

Comment: hey fuzzy i m new in symfony 1 cannot understand instead setting correct passwords for db still giving such kind of errors